# float type appear when use replace method in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [np.nan, 'None', 3],
        [np.nan, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
     ], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)

df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
print(df)

df.replace({'None': None}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
      a     b  c
0  None  None  3
1  None     5  6
2     7     8  9
     a    b  c
0  NaN  NaN  3
1  NaN  5.0  6
2  7.0  8.0  9
```

this is small example fo my case.
i wanna replace nan, "None" to None. so i use replace twice
first replace method work fine as i thought, but nan was reborn in second replace and all int is changed to float because of nan. i have no idea about why nan is reborn df.replace({'None': None}, inplace=True), how can i fix it?

Comment: What if `df.replace({'None': np.nan}, inplace=True)`?

Comment: you need nullable int dtype: `df.replace({'None': None}).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`, [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: Could I ask why you want to use None instead of NaN? For most cases, NaN is the best way to indicate a missing value in a DataFrame.

Comment: @wwnde it doesnt work.

Comment: @anky i use just "Int64" finally.

Comment: @ALS777 i expected none is more stable in aws service(glue, athena...). and actually, i dont know difference None(not exist) and nan(missing) exactly, None is closer what i wanna express in code. so i wanna use None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want integers in a column with `nan` values you need to use `pd.NA` instead. `nan` is a float and will force an array of integers to become a floating point. Check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

**Solution**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [np.nan, None, 3],
        [np.nan, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ], 
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],
)

# replace np.nan with pd.NA
# then convert columns types to Int32
df.fillna(pd.NA).astype('Int32')
```

```
Out[11]:
      a     b  c
0  <NA>  <NA>  3
1  <NA>     5  6
2     7     8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do is change it to `object`

```
out = df.replace({'None': None}).astype(object)
Out[10]: 
     a    b  c
0  NaN  NaN  3
1  NaN    5  6
2    7    8  9
```

Comment: even i dont use object type, your reply teach me variable way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the column type to be an integer instead of a float. You can use the nullable integer dtype introduced in pandas version 0.24.0.

With a column that is a regular integer dtype is automatically converted to a float dtype if it gets a null value. Note that if you use the pandas nullable integer dtype, the column will not become a float and the null value will be represented as `<NA>` the pandas.NA value.

Read more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: i know nullable integer type through your reply. thanks!